# copy over 100 files at a time with xarg or script?

Tags: directory, find, sleep, xargs, mv

I have over 1.3M files in a dir and I need to move them from `j:/hold` to `j:/hold2` (all while a java app 'watches' the dir for any files to drop in and process them)  I cannot just 'rename' the dir because the app crashes because the folder contains too many files.  I want to just copy over 100 files at a time into `j:/hold2` with `xargs` and `sleep` for 30 seconds.

I just want to move a certain number of files into the 'hold2' dir so that my java app can process them in a timely manner and not get overwhelmed with hundreds of thousands of files. Would it be better to try and script this out?  I have no idea on how that would be done :(

Would the following command work if I am already inside the correct dir?

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -l100 mv -t /mnt/hold2 -P 30 sleep
```

Comment: I am not understanding the `sleep` and `mv` that would not work on my `xargs` (Ubuntu). At least make sure you do `-print0` on the find and `-0` on `xargs` to prevent problems with files that have spaces in their names.

Comment: gotcha, thanks for the advice.  I'll add it in to my command that I run.